# Angular 2 Input NgModel converting String to number

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have the following inputs.

```
 <input type="radio" id="someId" name="someName" value="1" [(ngModel)]="someArray]"/>
<input type="radio" id="someId" name="someName" value="2" [(ngModel)]="someArray]"/>
<input type="radio" id="someId" name="someName" value="3" [(ngModel)]="someArray]"/>
```

The are getting stored to array as ["1", "2", "3"] as strings. I need them to store to the array as integers. How can I achiveve this?

Comment: In angular 1.x this was done with $parsers/$formatters I think in NG 2 the idea is to use "pipes" to achieve the same kind of functionality, would look into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. `[value] = "some array"`

The brackets keep the type intact.